# Office js addin: Can I send email from excel addin?

Tags: outlook-addin, office-addins, excel-addins

I am developing an excel add-in. Everything works fine but I would like to send the end result via email.
Is it possible to send a table range content with the outlook from excel addin?

Comment: The answer to the question you asked is "yes".

Comment: @FrankPl Could you elaborate? How can I do that? An example would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You can use the Exchange web services from your JS add-in. EWS is a SOAP based, XML protocol. There is no officially supported client libraries for JS, Outlook add-ins have built-in methods for making such calls. In case of Excel web add-ins you may consider using [ews-javascript-api](https://github.com/gautamsi/ews-javascript-api).

In case of Outlook add-ins you may find the [Call web services from an Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/web-services) page helpful.